# SQL select and match from multiple tables

Tags: sql

While I have looked at different examples on the internet I am having trouble selecting data from multiple tables. I have 2 tables.

```
     1st  has 'logUID', 'groupUID' field.
```

the other

```
    2nd has 'logUID' , 'User ID' , 'LogEntry' , 'LogTypeUID'
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the log entries where the LogUID match each other and return the groupUID field , so I know which group the log was against. When I have tried select's or joins I seem to be getting one logUID field repeating.

```
SELECT TOP 10000 [log].[dbo].[Logs].[LogUID], [log].[dbo].[LogGroups].[LogUID],     [Weblog].[dbo].[LogGroups].[GroupUID] 

FROM [log].[dbo].[LogGroups], [log].[dbo].[Logs] INNER JOIN [log].[dbo].[LogGroups] as LG
ON [log].[dbo].[Logs].[LogUID] = LG.LogUID ;
```

Any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `[LogGroups]` table in there twice...

- `FROM table1, table2` means `table1 CROSS JOIN table2`

So, just change your code to the following...

```
SELECT TOP 10000
  [Logs].[LogUID],
  [LogGroups].[LogUID],
  [LogGroups].[GroupUID]
FROM
  [log].[dbo].[Logs]
INNER JOIN
  [log].[dbo].[LogGroups]
    ON [Logs].[LogUID] = [LogGroups].LogUID ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra FROM `[log].[dbo].[LogGroups],`

Answer (score -1):

See first of all you need to create a relationship between the tables you have created. After creating a relationship you can either create a key relationship using the two columns. So that whatever data goes in the logUID field of first table, the same data goes in the logUID field of second table. So this would help you to fetch the data from both the tables.

Hope this would help.